# Broken documentation formatting Qt Assitant

Tags: qt

i've searched stackoverflow and this question has been done long time ago, but it doesn't have an answer.

I'm using debian testing 64 bits, and i installed qt libraries and programs from up-to-date repositories, and i get incorrect formatting for qt4 documentation.

Here it is how it should look:

[image]

And here is how it looks:
[image]

Has anyone had the same problem and found a solution?, i tried reinstalling different packages, but didn't work

Comment: The formatting has changed a bit from Qt4 to Qt5. For instance, in the Qt5 docs all links are green instead of blue. Personally, I liked the Qt4 layout better. What is bothering you exactly?

Comment: yes, but i've using it on another machine (debian testing 32 bits) and it looks like the first picture. The seoncd picture doesn't look good, and you get better and faster the structure of the text with good formatting. Of course, i can still understand it, but i wonder why it looks that way, i've seen it probably has to do with qt webkit package, but if it's that, i don't know how to solve it

Comment: Assistant was using QtWebKit before it was deprecated and removed. It is now using the QTextBrowser class that isn't as full featured as webkit. One thing you can do is build the QtWebKit module (or its [reboot](https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases)) and rebuild Assistant to use it.